# Understanding the Nutch Regex pattern

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I am very new to Nutch. I am using Nutch 2.3 to crawl a website, here i want to crawl only some links which matches a specific pattern. As we know for this we have to use `regex-urlfilter.txt`.. So I have configured something like below in my regex-urlfilter.txt file, but the result is 0 crawled URL's.

URL's I want to crawl should match below pattern:

```
http://abc.test.com/profiles/people/a/1.html
```

In the above URL, we can see `/a/1.html` at the end. I want to apply regex only at this part. the letter `'a' could be [a-z]` and the number `'1' could be [1-20]`. There is no change in the rest of the URL`( http://abc.test.com/profiles/people)`.

Hope my requirement is clear now

Below is what I have written in /bin/seed/urls.txt

```
http://abc.test.com/profiles/people/a/1.html
```

Also I tried with `http://abc.test.com/`

And below is my regex pattern in **regex-urlfilter.txt** file

```
# accept anything else
+^http://abc.test.com/profiles/people/([a-z]*\.)/([0-20]*\.).html
```

I am getting 0 URL's when I am crawling. I am assuming that I am making some mistakes either in **urls.txt** file or in **regex-urlfilter.txt**

Will somebody please help me in configuring properly

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Nutch Tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial), you need to use a regex to the variable part, and you are doing that right, but your regular expression needs a small correction.

The literal dot `.` in regex must be escaped. `([a-z]*\.)/([0-20]*\.).html` means *lowercase English letters, 0 or more occurrences, then a literal `.`, then a literal `/`, then 0 or more `0`s, `1`s, `2`s (`[0-20]*`), followed by a literal `.`, and then any character and `html` literal string*.

So, you are trying to allow strings like

```
http://abc.test.com/profiles/people/./.^html
```

See, you require `.` to be before the final `/`. It is not the case, I believe.

So, use

```
+^http://abc\.test\.com/profiles/people/[a-zA-Z]+/([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\.html
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2uV1/1)